# How to acces to an hash value if the hash is in array? PERL

Tags: perl

I have an array of hashes and i want to change the value in keys how can i do that?

```
my @AoH = ();
for (my $i=0; $i < scalar @fileRows; $i++) { 
    my %fields =();
    @fields{@wordsAll} = (1) x @wordsAll; #key names are from array
    push @AoH, {%fields};
}
```

Comment: Could you be clearer, please?

Comment: btw, `push @AoH, {%fields};` creates a new hash for nothing. You want `push @AoH, \%fields;`

Comment: It is entirely unclear what you goal is.  Please edit the question to provide more detail in explaining both your setup and your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Foreach and get the hash reference for each array index.. in order to do hash operations you need to cast it to a hash with %{}

```
  my @AoH = ();

  foreach my $hash (@AoH){
      #edit the hash here
      $hash->{'key'} = 'value';
      my @keys = keys %$hash;
      my @values = values %$hash;
  }
```